# What's the difference between FourierDCT and dct2 in matlab

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

```
dct2 2-D discrete cosine transform.
B = dct2(A) returns the discrete cosine transform of A.
The matrix B is the same size as A and contains the
discrete cosine transform coefficients.
```

[image]

In Wolfram Mathematica, we have 4 kinds of FourierDCT, however none is the same with matlab.

[image]

Why? Is it possible to obtain same results that we can compare the results about some similar tasks.

```
FourierDCT[{1,2},#]&/@Range[4]
FourierDCT[{1,2,3},#]&/@Range[4]
FourierDCT[{1,2,3,4},#]&/@Range[4]
FourierDCT[{1,2,3,4,5},#]&/@Range[4]
```

Comment: Maybe `dct2[list_]:=MapAt[#/Sqrt[2]&,Sqrt[2]*FourierDCT[list],1]` ?

Comment: Maybe type II, with a different normalization coefficient.  See https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dct2.html

Comment: Note that MATLAB is doing a 2D transform, while Mathematica is doing a 1D transform.  I think MATLAB will be doing a transform along the 1D dimension, which may be confusing.

Comment: @mikado This isn't a problem. Modifying the input to e.g. `{{1,2}}`, you'll see the output is the same. user293787's answer is correct.

Comment: @user293787 Post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normalization conventions differ. This should work:

```
dct2[list_?VectorQ] := MapAt[#/Sqrt[2]&,Sqrt[2]*FourierDCT[list],1];
dct2[mat_?MatrixQ] := Transpose[MapAt[#/Sqrt[2]&,
                       Transpose[MapAt[#/Sqrt[2]&,2*FourierDCT[mat],1]],1]];

idct2[list_?VectorQ] := 1/Sqrt[2]*FourierDCT[MapAt[#*Sqrt[2]&,list,1],3];
idct2[mat_?MatrixQ] := 1/2*FourierDCT[Transpose[MapAt[#*Sqrt[2]&,
                        Transpose[MapAt[#*Sqrt[2]&,mat,1]],1]],3];
```

Example:

```
x = dct2[{1,2,3,4,5}]
(* {6.7082,-3.1495,2.35514*10^-16,-0.28399,0.} *)

idct2[x]
(* {1.,2.,3.,4.,5.} *)
```